# Error referring to the same Mongo.Collection from two .js files in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this line in two .js files in Meteor:

```
merchants = new Mongo.Collection('merchants');
```

It blows up with the error message below. Why?

Tried adding `var`

Removing the line in one of the files helps.

What am I doing wrong?

```
`W20150614-11:20:50.527(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\signUp\signUp.js:1:48
W20150614-11:20:50.527(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\signUp\signUp.js:54:3
W20150614-11:20:50.529(-7)? (STDERR)     at E:\work\meteor3\app\merchant\.m
eteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
W20150614-11:20:50.529(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150614-11:20:50.529(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\
I\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bund
le\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
W20150614-11:21:03.189(-7)? (STDERR)
W20150614-11:21:03.190(-7)? (STDERR) C:\Users\I\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\m
eteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\
future.js:245
W20150614-11:21:03.191(-7)? (STDERR)
throw(ex);
W20150614-11:21:03.191(-7)? (STDERR)
      ^
W20150614-11:21:03.192(-7)? (STDERR) Error: A method named '/merchants/insert' is already defined
W20150614-11:21:03.193(-7)? (STDERR)     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1461
:1
W20150614-11:21:03.193(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/
underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
W20150614-11:21:03.194(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object]._.extend.methods (pa
ckages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1459:1)
W20150614-11:21:03.194(-7)? (STDERR)     at [object Object].Mongo.Collection._de
fineMutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:904:1)
W20150614-11:21:03.195(-7)? (STDERR)     at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo
/collection.js:209:1)
W20150614-11:21:03.196(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\signUp\signUp.js:1:48
W20150614-11:21:03.196(-7)? (STDERR)     at app\signUp\signUp.js:54:3
W20150614-11:21:03.197(-7)? (STDERR)     at E:\work\meteor3\app\merchant\.m
eteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:222:10
W20150614-11:21:03.198(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150614-11:21:03.199(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (C:\Users\
I\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bund
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `new Mongo.Collection` declaration per collection in meteor app.

Comment: Am I to use global variables for collections?

Comment: Yes, it will be shared on server and client

Comment: Yikes! I wish I could use local variables. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: While at it.. it seems that the convention is to uppercase Merchants in my example. Why is that? I tried to search, could not find anything. The Java transplant in me is confused.